# Как подключить Mysql к приложению на java7 и Tomcat 7

Tags: база-данных, tomcat, jdbc, java-7

Есть приложение на сервлетах, используется java 7 и Tomcat 7 - не могу прикрутить базу данных - пробую jdbc, выдает org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class [org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet])    и could not create connection to database server

Answer (score 0):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html
по ссылке есть все сопоставление зависимостей и версий для подключения jdbc